# Redeclaration of static constexpr data members?

Tags: c++

**N4687:**

---

[Annex D (normative) Compatibility features]

D.1 Redeclaration of static constexpr data members

1 For compatibility with prior C++ International Standards, a constexpr static data member may be redundantly
redeclared outside the class with no initializer. This usage is deprecated. [ Example:

```
struct A {
static constexpr int n = 5; // definition (declaration in C++ 2014)
};

constexpr int A::n; // redundant declaration (definition in C++ 2014)
```

— end example ]

---

I don't have a good command of English, so I am confronted with several questions when learning standard(I'm just coming from odr-use)

1. `This usage is deprecated` which `usage` does here mean?
2. - definition (declaration in C++ 2014)
   - redundant declaration (definition in C++ 2014)

the two comments confuse me. 
Here is two possibility:

i.

- Until C++ 2014(c++14/1y), `static constexpr int n = 5;` is a `definition`. `constexpr int A::n;` is a `redundant declaration`.
- Since C++17(or after c++14), `static constexpr int n = 5;` is a `declaration`. `constexpr int A::n;` is a `definition`

ii.

- Since C++17(or after c++14), `static constexpr int n = 5;` is a `definition`. `constexpr int A::n;` is a `redundant declaration`.
- Before c++17(which include c++ 2014), `static constexpr int n = 5` is a `declaration`. `constexpr int A::n;` is a `definition`.

`i` and `ii`, which is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *Redeclaring the `constexpr static` data member outside the class* is deprecated. That is, in C++17 you should only have the definition inside the class and nothing outside.
2. Second option: C++17 makes the in-class thingy a *definition*, and the outer thingy a *redundant declaration*.
   The parentheses recall that in C++14, they were respectively a *declaration* and a *definition*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still have a question: Now that redeclaring is deprecated in c++17, why c++17 modify `definition` to `redundant declaration`(just as option2 mentions)? It is a conflict, isn't?

Comment: @czxyl because if the out-of-class one was still a definition, you'd get two definitions, which is an ODR error. Hence the "redundant declaration" wording that essentially means ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is really correct. I found a good explanation of definition and declaration [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1412523/2204581):

> Declaration "Somewhere, there exists a foo".
>
> Definition: "...and here it is!"

For regular class members, they can be *declared* in the header file and *defined* in the implementation (cpp) file.

What C++17 changes is that when you provide a compile-time constant as the value for that class member, it is a *definition* and you are defining it in the class definition. You can neither redefine it outside of the class, nor redeclare it.

> This usage is deprecated which usage does here mean?

Usage refers to the redeclaration.